# How to change file extension using java

Tags: java, file-rename

In the below code I am checking whether file ends with **CSV** **extension**. 
My question is : If file ends with **xls extension** I need to change to **csv**.

Example: AA.xls file to AA.CSV (only extension change).

```
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

                    System.out.println("CSV Files Present in Dir are:   " + name);

                    return name.toLowerCase().endsWith("csv");
                 }
            });
```

Comment: `fileA.renameTo(fileB);`, with fileA is old name, fileB is new name(with extension)

Comment: why don't you change your accept method to accept xls as well?

Answer (score 1):

The [File.renameTo(File dest)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) function is your friend. So, you have a file, get it's path, replace *xls* with *csv* and create a new *File* object from that. Then rename your file and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply change an xls-file to csv by changing the file extension it might not be readable afterwards, unless the file really is CSV "encoded".

To simply rename the file use blalasaadri's answer and use `File.renameTo(File dest)`, but if you have a real XLS file, you need a library like Apache POI to parse the file and then store the data in a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a method `renameTo` in the `File` class. You can use it to change the extension of the file.

Have a look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
String name="a.xls";
        String []z=name.split("\\.");
        if(z[1].equals("xls")){
            z[1]=".csv";
        }
        System.out.println(z[0]+z[1]);
```

Comment: This assumes there is only one `.` in the file name.

Comment: @Alan I assume Op can  write a method which passes an arguement of String type

Comment: I don't see how that relates. My concern was for situations where `name = "bar.foo.xls";`. With the above code, this xls file would be ignored, since the element following the first `.` is not xls.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> // File (or directory) with old name
> File file = new File("oldname");
> // File (or directory) with new name
> File file2 = new File("newname");
> // Rename file (or directory)
> boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);
> if (!success)
> {
> // File was not successfully renamed
> }
> ```